# Override user.name and user.email used in git with the ones used in GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, ssh-keys

On our GitLab CE server, and the users (members) have in their profile the name and email.

They use a personal SSH Key to authenticate.

If they commit something on git, the commit belongs to an author and a committer, both of witch are setup in the command line. Using ´git config user.name somebody´or ´git config user.email some@email.com´ .

The problem is, that the user do not have this information set up correctly and also they can impersonate other persons.

How can I ignore the information passed in the user config, and use the one that GitLab uses?

Answer (score 3):

If you use ssh the authentication mechanism should be taken from there but commit information has nothing to do with the authentication.

#### For example:

Lets say i set my environment properly with the following info:

```
git config --global user.name somebody 
git config --global user.email some@email.com
```

Now my default committer will be the above.
But i can still **overwrite** it like this:

```
git -c user.name="Darth Vader" -c user.email="star@wars.com" commit -m "Message"
```

Now the data in the commit will be the following:

[image]

So as you can see there is no way you can verify that the user is set correctly.

---

#### Workaround - what can you do

You can use server side hook to verify that the committer is an existing user under your server by collecting the information and processing it before the code is being pushed to your server.